# Fail to load tsv for d3.js bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filesystems, wampserver

I'm using d3.js for charting, I'm getting this error while I want to load custom data from local system.

> Failed to load file:///C:/Users/foo/Desktop/d3/barChart/data.tsv:
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Inside `d3` folder there is the index.html and the data.tsv.

I have installed WAMP Server and it's active.

### Update

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, "%"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });
});

</script>
```

**data.tsv**

```
letter  frequency

A   .08167
B   .01492
C   .02782
D   .04253
```

Comment: It does not look like you are using WAMPServer at all as you have `file:///C:/......` in the error message

Comment: Are you running the html file by clicking on the filename in explorer? You shoudl load the browser and put a url in the address bar, like `localhost/project1/index.html`

Comment: @RiggsFolly wamp server icon is "green". How can solve it?

Comment: It maybe green, but you are not using it unless you launch the `index.html` as suggested in the previous comment

Comment: Thankts for the answer. So how can  solve? Now i'm confused

Comment: Seems like your not using wamp correctly since you are going to a local path on your pc. This is why your are getting CORS errors. you can read up about CORS here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS . I think what you want to achieve is set the file somewhere online and reach out to it via a webservice. This is where CORS will kick in

Comment: create a folder in `C:\wamp\www\` like `C:\wamp\www\project1`. Then open your browser and enter `locahost/project1` in the address bar. Now you will be using the Apache web server part of WAMPServer.

Comment: Oh, if you installed the 64bit WAMPServer the folder will be called `C:\wamp64`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i followed your advices so i wrote this: localhost/barChart. Inside barchart folder there is `index.html` and a `data.tsv`. This is the error shown:  `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: well at least now you are using the web server

Comment: But as you have posted no code, it now become impossible to be of any more assistance

Comment: Yes, but Unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: i will post, see update.

Comment: @RiggsFolly code updated.

Comment: Your code works on my local rig. Uninstall your WAMP server, download a fresh one and re-install it.Obvious if you haven't anothers projects on it: on that case you can use Laragon server portable to test this one.